# Error while moving data from excel to access

Tags: java, excel, ms-access, ucanaccess

I am trying to copy data from an excel file to an access file , and I'm executing some queries, deleting a table then creating it then inserting the data, knowing that my table contains some spaces 'list A' , the query shows an error while putting some brackets around the table name.

```
public static Vector writetableA(String fileName) {
    Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
    try {

        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
        // POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIter.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
            // Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
            List list = new ArrayList();
            while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                list.add(myCell);

            }
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/gfas1/Desktop/DHL Addendum_Oct 8 - final/Updated DHL.accdb");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeQuery("DROP TABLE [list A]");
            stmt.executeQuery(
                    "CREATE TABLE [list A]  (ID VARCHAR(255),First VARCHAR(255),Name VARCHAR(255),Last Name VARCHAR(255),EmailAddress VARCHAR(255),Tuition Paid VARCHAR(255),Gender VARCHAR(255),Nation of  Birth VARCHAR(255),Nation of Ctizen VARCHAR(255),AGE VARCHAR(255),Level VARCHAR(255),Major VARCHAR(255),Concentration VARCHAR(255), Minor VARCHAR(255), Double Major/Dual Degree VARCHAR(255)   ,Class  VARCHAR(255),Admit Term VARCHAR(255),   Catalog term VARCHAR(255),   Advisor    Term VARCHAR(255),GPA   VARCHAR(255),Term Attempt Hrs VARCHAR(255), Term passed Hrs VARCHAR(255),   Term Earned Hrs VARCHAR(255),Overall GPA    VARCHAR(255),Overall Attemp Hrs VARCHAR(255),   Overall Earned Hrs  VARCHAR(255),Overall GPA Hours  VARCHAR(255),Repeated Overall VARCHAR(255), Repeated Term VARCHAR(255),     Withdrawn Overall VARCHAR(255), Withdrawn Term VARCHAR(255),    Acad VARCHAR(255), Standing VARCHAR(255),Full/Part  VARCHAR(255),SAT_Verbal VARCHAR(255),SAT_MATH VARCHAR(255)");
            stmt.executeQuery(
                    "INSERT INTO [list A] (ID,First,Name,Last Name,EmailAddress,Tuition Paid,Gender,Nation of  Birth,Nation of Ctizen,AGE,Level,Major,Concentration,    Minor,  "
                            + "Double Major/Dual Degree ,Class  ,Admit Term,    Catalog term,   "
                            + "Advisor  Term ,GPA   ,Term Attempt Hrs,  Term passed Hrs,    "
                            + "Term Earned Hrs  ,Overall GPA    ,Overall Attemp Hrs,    Overall "
                            + "Earned Hrs   ,Overall GPA Hours  ,Repeated Overall,  Repeated Term,"
                            + " Withdrawn Overall,  Withdrawn Term, Acad, Standing  ,Full/Part  ,SAT_Verbal,"
                            + " SAT_MATH) VALUES('" + list.get(0) + "','" + list.get(1) + "','" + list.get(2)
                            + "','" + list.get(3) + "','" + list.get(4) + "','" + list.get(5) + "','" + list.get(6)
                            + "','" + list.get(7) + "','" + list.get(8) + "','" + list.get(9) + "','" + list.get(10)
                            + "','" + list.get(11) + "','" + list.get(12) + "','" + list.get(13) + "','"
                            + list.get(14) + "','" + list.get(15) + "','" + list.get(16) + "','" + list.get(17)
                            + "','" + list.get(18) + "','" + list.get(19) + "','" + list.get(20) + "','"
                            + list.get(21) + "','" + list.get(22) + "','" + list.get(23) + "','" + list.get(24)
                            + "','" + list.get(25) + "','" + list.get(26) + "','" + list.get(27) + "','"
                            + list.get(28) + "','" + list.get(29) + "','" + list.get(31) + "','" + list.get(32)
                            + "','" + list.get(33) + "','" + list.get(34) + "'");
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}
```

error recieved:

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 unexpected
>   token: [  at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:218)
>     at main.writetableA(main.java:492)  at main.main(main.java:465)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: [  at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)    at
>   net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:216)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: [
>     at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserBase.checkIsIdentifier(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileDrop(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)    ... 5 more

Comment: Some field names have spaces and/or punctuation/special characters. Must enclose in `[ ]` delimiters: `[Nation of  Birth]`. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: You really want to create fields `First` and `Name`?

Comment: No this is by a mistake, i corrected that, i tried to enclose the field names by a [] but the same problem appears

Comment: As far as the SQL statements, brackets are necessary. Also, parameters need apostrophe delimiters for text, # for date/time, nothing for number type fields. I don't understand Java enough to know if there are other issues with code.